# Why does SystemTriggerType.NetworkStateChange trigger multiple times?

Tags: windows-8, background-process

I'm trying to check for network state changes in a background task on Windows 8. You can find the exact details on registering a background task [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj553413.aspx).

I've registered several events to test which is the best fit:

```
BackgroundTaskManager.RegisterBackgroundTask(
    BackgroundTaskManager.NetworkTaskEntryPoint,
    Constants.NetworkAvailable,
    new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.NetworkStateChange, false),
    new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable));
BackgroundTaskManager.RegisterBackgroundTask(
    BackgroundTaskManager.NoNetworkTaskEntryPoint,
    Constants.NetworkUnAvailable,
    new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.NetworkStateChange, false),
    new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetNotAvailable));
BackgroundTaskManager.RegisterBackgroundTask(
    BackgroundTaskManager.InternetTaskEntryPoint,
    Constants.InternetAvailable,
    new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.InternetAvailable, false),
    null);
```

To test I enable flight mode and disable it. I get following events (systemtrigger/condition):

- NetworkStateChange/InternetNotAvailable
- The program '[xxx]
  backgroundTaskHost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 1
  (0x1).
- NetworkStateChange/InternetNotAvailable
- The program '[xxx] backgroundTaskHost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 1
  (0x1).
- NetworkStateChange/InternetNotAvailable
- The program '[xxx]
  backgroundTaskHost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 1
  (0x1).
- NetworkStateChange/InternetNotAvailable
- The program '[xxx]
  backgroundTaskHost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 1
  (0x1).
- NetworkStateChange/InternetAvailable InternetAvailable
  (SystemTrigger)
- NetworkStateChange/InternetAvailable
- The program
  '[xxx] backgroundTaskHost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with
  code 1 (0x1).
- NetworkStateChange/InternetAvailable
- The program '[xxx]
  backgroundTaskHost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 1
  (0x1).
- NetworkStateChange/InternetAvailable
- The program '[xxx]
  backgroundTaskHost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 1
  (0x1).

So I'm getting the NetworkStateChange with condition Unavailable 4 times, with condition available 4 times and InternetAvailable once (which is correct).

In the background task I do nothing more than following code to test:

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    // keep track that we're no longer connected
    Debug.WriteLine("Background " + taskInstance.Task.Name + " Starting...");
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[BackgroundTaskManager.NetworkConnectedKey] = true;
}
```

I've also tried adding a GetDeferral(), but since there's no async code, there's no real issue there. Note that the code in all methods is also the same and all tasks are only registered once.

Comment: that is normal. network state doesn't just cover access to the internet. It covers changes in network adapter availability, wifi connections, etc. If all you want to know if internet is accessible at this time just use InternetAvailable trigger.

Comment: Question is: how to know if internet dropped (in a single event)? Also the amount of triggers depend on the size of the code being executed.